# How can we solve the issue of Mesh WiFi making our speed 50%?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, mesh-networking

I tried a "Mesh WiFi network", using Linksys MX4200, but it seems this way:

1. If my computer is connected to Unit 1 of the 3 Linksys MX4200 in the study room, then I can copy file from my computer to the NAS at 50MB / s. (50 megabytes per second).
2. However, let's say I turn on a Unit 2, and place it in the bedroom, now the computer is connected to this Unit 2 because it is "a better signal".  Now when I copy a file, half the bandwidth is used to move data from the computer to Unit 2, and half the bandwidth is used to move data from Unit 2 to Unit 1.  So my speed is now 25 MB / s, using "a better signal".

So how can this problem be solved?

Comment: MX4200 is supposed to be tri-band, with a dedicated backhaul radio. Are you sure it’s set up correctly? How’s the connection between the two mesh nodes?

Comment: "Now when I copy a file, half the bandwidth is used to move data from the computer to Unit 2, and half the bandwidth is used to move data from Unit 2 to Unit 1." - What makes you think this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make unit 2 expose connectivity on a different radio / band from unit 1. For example, if you have unit 1 on 2.4 GHz band, make sure unit 2 accepts connections only on the 5GHz band, and connects with unit 1 in 2.4 GHz band. Or vice versa. Or similarly if using a high 5GHz band radio (for channels 100+).

Comment: Ot use an alternative backhaul medium like ethernet or Ethernet over Powerline.